# Sharing a MySQLdb connection between Python classes

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I'm working with Python 3 using MySQLdb and I need to be able to share the DB connection between classes.

I have the main script `play.py` tha calls other classes (`player.py`, `team.py`, etc) and some of those classes need to access the DB. Which is the best approach to do so?

Following the discussion [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200522/how-to-deal-with-database-connections-in-a-python-library-module), I created a `Mysql` class that creates the connection and handles the queries. But won't importing that new class in `play.py` and `team.py` create a new connection for each?

Is there a way to just create one connection and use that same connection everywhere with no need to create a new connection for each class?

Comment: Pass the open DB connection as a parameter to all other class constructors. BTW, you confuse classes (`Play`, 'Team`') and modules that contain them (`play.py`, `team.py`), and this may be a part of your problem.

Comment: Thought of passing the DB connection as a parameter to the classes' constructor, and that'd surely use only 1 DB connection. Is there any other approach that doesn't pass the DB connection as a parameter? Like making a super global variable visible within every class?

Comment: BTW, thanks for the module/class clarification

Comment: Any global variable is bad, and a superglobal is the worst.